# Sub domain issue

Tags: hosting, dns

I am new to web hosting, never done it before. I am working on my assignment for uni. and wanted to know if I can create multiple subdomains when I am hosted with a webhost.

I want to be able to do the following:
1. users can sign up and get a subdomain of their choice.
2. users are allocated a limited webspace
3. The access to file types need to be controlled. In the sense that users can only upload/download certain file types like html, htm, jpg, gif, zip etc.
4. Users can have forms that work only within their subdomain.
for example the domain name is www.example.com
the user signs up for [mysite.example.com...] where "mysite" is the subdomain.

Comment: Usually you can but that depends on the webhost. For example if hey have a management panel such as cPanel which has features that allow you to interact with your own code it could create the subdomains without problems but some other hosts may have it hard or not even possible ( in the sense of allowing the client to control the ability of creating sub domains). In some cases you can request the webhost company to enable wildcard on your domain which i belive would be the best option for your case this way you can simple make your own code to determinate where a subdomain will be sent to.

Comment: 3. if you are controlling the users access from your own code then yes, you can limit them. 2. if you control the same from your code you can block your users once they meet their quota... You could perhaps provide more information that might help us figure out what you have available to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about several different things here. Firstly to enable a user to define an account with their own subdomain would best be tackled by using a wildcard DNS entry for your domain. Whether your hosting company offer or allow that should be your first question.

Once you have that setup then pretty much everything else you want to do can be controlled by the application you build.